# I encounter issues when retrieving metadata for tokens on the Cardano network

Tags: metadata

I encountered an error while retrieving token metadata as follows:

```
var policyId = '8bca871dcd4f1dd9588d901d02677b6d2413fd19e4c8febfc353edff';
var assetName = '5045505041'; // PEPPA 

var subject = policyId + assetName;

await blockfrostProvider.fetchAssetMetadata(
  subject,
);
```

But when I use [https://tokens.cardano.org/metadata/{subject}](https://tokens.cardano.org/metadata/%7Bsubject%7D), it works. So, where is the issue on my part?